# Reference books for classical mechanics with good number of solved examples

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations

I am looking for some classical mechanics reference book with a good number of solved problems.

Comment: Can you add more details? What level? Just particle mechanics?

Comment: Bob, see the question I've linked. Search for the heading *Problem books* and there's a link to several popular books.